# What is the smart way to display comments under posts?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I can currently write both my posts and replies to my database but now I am stuck as to how to display my replies to my specific posts and how to display posts with the comments under them. Any tips help especially pointers to the proper documentation concerning a problem like this.

routes.py

```
@app.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, author=current_user,)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New Post Created', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post', form=form, legend='New Post')


@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>")
def post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    return render_template('post.html', title=post.title, post=post,)


@app.route("/post/reply", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_reply():
    form = ReplyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        reply = Reply(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, author=current_user,)
        db.session.add(reply)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('reply posted', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('Reply.html', title='New Reply', form=form, legend='New Reply')
```

post.html

```
{% block content %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + post.author.image_file) }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{{ url_for('user_posts', username=post.author.username) }}">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted}}</small>
        {% if post.author == current_user %}
          <div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('update_post', post_id=post.id) }}">[ Update ]</a>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('new_reply', post_id=post.id) }}">[ Reply ]</a>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('delete_post', post_id=post.id) }}">[ Delete ]</a>
          </div>
        {% else %}
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <div>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('new_reply', post_id=post.id ) }}">[ Reply ]</a>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: When you load a post in „post“, also load the comments, where a foreign key from your post database matches the primary key of your post. Then assemble the template. Pretty basic stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your model to connect both comments and posts in a many-to-one relationship, this can be achieved. (many comments are related to one post)

---

```py
from app         import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime    import datetime

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id       = db.Column(db.Integer,     primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64),  unique = True)
    email    = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(500))

class Post(db.Model):
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title       = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content     = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id     = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

class Reply(db.Model):
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id     = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id     = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    content     = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Now you can get all replies for the post by simpy querying the Reply table with a `post_id`

```py
from .models import Reply

replies = Reply.query.filter_by(post_id=`your_post_id_here').all()
```

---

You can take that `replies` list and render it in a template

Answer (score 0):

- Define a table called comments
- Define relationship posts-comments as 1-to-many, with appropriate backrefs
- under each post do:

```
{%for comment in post.comments%}

{%endfor%}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "Define relationship posts-comments as 1-to-many," I already have a db table called "reply", I remember there was a post from 2015 about a similar question that I had but I cant find it.

Comment: For example in [this file](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/shopyo/blob/dev/shopyo/modules/category/models.py) Category has 1-to-many relationship with SubCategory. See how it's done using flask-sqlalchemy